# why is Matlab slow in for loop with large number of iterations but fast with a small number of iterations?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, data-extraction, slowdown

I am running a function to extract some information from 100,000+ patient xray dicom files. the files are stored within a veracrypt encryption container for security purposes.

when i run the function on a small sample of files it performs really quickly, however when i run the function on the entire dataset it is very slow in comparison, going from several files per second to 1 file per second (approximately).

i was wandering why this is happening? i have tried storing the data on an ssd and on a normal hard drive and get the same sort of slow down when using a larger dataset compared to a small one.

i have added the code below for reference but haven't commented it fully yet.. this is for my thesis so i will do it once i get the extraction finished..

**thanks for any help.**

```
function [ DB, corrupted_files ] = extract_from_dcm( folder_name )
%EXTRACT_FROM_DCM Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

if nargin == 0
    folder_name = 'I:\Find and Treat\MXU Old Backup\2005';
end

Database_Check = strcat(folder_name, '\DataBase.mat');

if exist(Database_Check, 'file')

    load(Database_Check);
    entry_start = length(DB) + 1;

else

    entry_start = 1;
    [ found_dicoms ] = recursive_search( folder_name );

end

mat_file_location = strcat(folder_name, '\DataBase.mat');
excel_DB_file = strcat(folder_name, '\DataBase.xlsx');
excel_Corrupted_file = strcat(folder_name, '\Corrupted_Files.xlsx');

% the recursive search creates a struct with the path for each
% dcm file found. the list is then recursivly used to locate
% the image and extract the relevant information from it.


fprintf('---------------------------------------------\n');
fprintf('Start Patient Data Extraction\n');
tic
h = waitbar(0,'','Name','Patient Data Extraction');
entry_end = length(found_dicoms);

if entry_end == 0
    %     set(handles.info_box, 'String', 'No Dicom Files Found in this Folder or its Subfolders');
else
    %     set(handles.info_box, 'String', 'Congratulations Dicom Files have been found Look Through the Data Base using the Buttons Below....Press Save Button to save the Database. (Database Save format is EXCEL SpreadSheet and MAT file');

    for  kk = entry_start : entry_end
        progress = kk/entry_end;
        progress_percent = round(progress * 100);
        waitbar(progress,h, sprintf('%d%%   %d/%d of images processed', progress_percent, kk, entry_end));

        img_full_path = found_dicoms(kk).name;

        %         search_path = folder_name;
        %         img_full_path = strrep(img_full_path, search_path, '');

        try              %# Attempt to perform some computation
            dicom_info = dicominfo(img_full_path); %# The operation you are trying to perform goes here

            try              %# Attempt to perform some computation
                dicom_read = dicomread(dicom_info); %# The operation you are trying to perform goes here

                old = dicominfo(img_full_path);

                DB(kk).StudyDate = old.StudyDate;
                DB(kk).StudyTime = old.StudyTime;


                if isfield(old.PatientName, 'FamilyName')
                    DB(kk).Forename = old.PatientName.FamilyName;
                else
                    DB(kk).Forename = 'NA';
                end

                if isfield(old.PatientName, 'GivenName')
                    DB(kk).LastName = old.PatientName.GivenName;
                else
                    DB(kk).LastName = 'NA';
                end

                if isfield(old, 'PatientSex')
                    DB(kk).PatientSex = old.PatientSex;
                else
                    DB(kk).PatientSex = 'NA';
                end

                if isempty(old.PatientBirthDate)
                    DB(kk).PatientBirthDate = '00000000';
                else
                    DB(kk).PatientBirthDate = old.PatientBirthDate;
                end

                if strcmp(old.Manufacturer, 'Philips Medical Systems')
                    DB(kk).Van = '1';
                else
                    DB(kk).Van = '0';% section to represent organising by different vans
                end

                DB(kk).img_Path = img_full_path;

                save(mat_file_location,'DB','found_dicoms');

            catch exception  %# Catch the exception
                fprintf('read - file %d corrupt.\n',kk);
                continue       %# Pass control to the next loop iteration
            end



        catch exception  %# Catch the exception
            fprintf('info - file %d corrupt.\n',kk);
            continue       %# Pass control to the next loop iteration
        end


    end

end


[ corrupted_files, DB ] = corruption_check( DB, found_dicoms, folder_name );


toc
fprintf('End Patient Data Extraction\n');
fprintf('---------------------------------------------\n');

fprintf('---------------------------------------------\n');
fprintf('Start Saving Extracted Data \n');
tic


save(mat_file_location,'DB','corrupted_files','found_dicoms');

if isempty(DB)
    msg = sprintf('No Dicom Files Found');
    msgbox(strcat(msg));
else
    DB_table = struct2table(DB);
    writetable(DB_table, excel_DB_file);
end

close(h);

toc
fprintf('End Saving Extracted Data \n');
fprintf('---------------------------------------------\n');

end
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there without any supporting evidence: You should really pre-allocate that `DB` array and it doesn't look like you do... You know how many elements there will be, specifically `entry_end - entry_start + 1`. Matlab should be warning you about this when you do `DB(kk)` as that can cause a reallocation since you keep changing its size (which is quite slow). To be really sure, run the [profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).

Comment: Updating that waitbar is probably costing you a lot of execution time. Graphics updates in a loop are very expensive. Try commenting that out to see if it helps. Better yet, use the profiler.

Comment: cool thanks, ye i plan to do the pre-allocation and i'll look into the waitbar. the issue is that as the code is, the larger the loop the slower it gets, i can't understand why this would be the case..

Comment: Well, see if those changes remove it (it is believable that a reallocation can cause it to slow down as it gets larger, maybe true with the waitbar too), but if not, you should collect [tic/tocks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) for every iteration and show the decrease in perf as well as use the profiler to narrow down the issue.

Comment: i did the preallocation and used the profiler but no noticeable difference.. when processing images in the 10's of thousands it is still much slower per image than when dealing with images in the hundreds. i didn't remove the waitbar as i really need it to keep track of what image is currently being processed.

Comment: @bilaly umm...you should post the results of your profiler (and tic/tocs to show the performance does in fact slow down as it iterates, or whether it is a random spike, vs averaging)? Did you check what lines of code are the slowest? Also, why do you save the `DB` vector every loop iteration? why not...after it has completed?

Comment: i shall re-run all tests and post results (it will take a while).. i save DB (which is a struct that contains the extracted patient data) each time in order to be able to cancel the operation and pick up where i left off later on without re-doing the same images again since there are so many of them to process and i can't let the computer run continuously till it finishes by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks for all the help..

My problem was the saving at the end of each iteration but the biggest problem was the line where i run the dicomread function. i changed the saving to occur for every 20 images processed.

I also removed the preallocation suggested in the comments to see what difference it made without the dicromread and saving a swell. it was considerably slower than with the preallocation.

... i just need to find a solution for dicomread (which i was using as a way to check if the file was corrupt or not).

Comment: i'd like to but it says i have to wait 2 days before i can accept it.